# Umbraco 7 - Disable miniprofiler

Tags: umbraco, miniprofiler

We are soon going to production and want to disable mini-profiler. We have set:
`umbracoDebugMode=false` and trace enabled=false in `web.config` transform.

I can confirm that these values are being set in web config upon release but when I browse to site I can see results from the `StartupProfiler url (site.com/mini-profiler-resources/results)`

I think we are missing something :)

Grateful for any help

Answer (score 0):

Are you building in release mode and/or setting

`<compilation debug=“false”>`

in web.config?

Comment: Thx for the response.  Yes , compilation debug is set to false but I don't biuld in release mode. Maybe that's the issue, right?

Comment: I rebuilt in release mode and set the above parameters but still same result. I can still se StartupProfiler results